# If statement firing when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

Line 14 should fire if there are no commands with the guild id,

Line 15 should fire if the user has no commands in that guild, 
but

`!commands @Rusty#2746` returns `No commands in this guild.` in the server `Go away`.  (I have a command in this server)

`!commands @Rusty#2746` returns `No commands in this guild.` **AND** the actual command in the server `SurgicalGoblin`.  ( I have a command in this server)

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
if (args.length !== 1) return message.reply("Incorrect arguments, " + args.length + " given, 1 required.");
if (message.mentions.users.size !== 1) return message.reply("You must mention a user to view the commands of.");

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../jsonFiles") + "/customCommands.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(data);

  if (arrayOfObjects.commands.length === 0) return message.reply("No custom commands found.");

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.commands.length; i++) {
  console.log(message.guild.id) // matches the guild_id in json file
    if (message.guild.id !== arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id) return message.reply("No commands in guild.");
    if (message.guild.id !== arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id && user.id !== arrayOfObjects.commands[i].user_id) return message.reply(user.username + " has no commands in this guild.");

    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../jsonFiles") + "/customCommands.json", JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects, null, 2), "utf-8", function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0x08F258)
      .setAuthor("Custom Commands for " + user.username, message.author.avatarURL)
      .addField(arrayOfObjects.commands[i].command_name, arrayOfObjects.commands[i].command_reply)
       return message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
    });
  }
});
```

JSON: https://hastebin.com/zucogajita.json

Comment: Is it possible there is a type mismatch? We don't see how `message.guild.id` is defined...is it, like `arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id`, also a string?

Comment: In line 13 I logged it and it gave me the correct guild id. `message.guild.id` is built into Discord.js (framework I am using).

Comment: But even if the value apparently matches based on the log statement, the type could be different. For example, try changing your inequality operator on line 14 from `!==` to `!=` ... does the `if` condition still evaluate to true?

Comment: @nb1987 I am getting the same response with that `No commands in guild`.

Comment: If you `console.log(arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id)`, what is the output? (By the way you can add a `debugger;` statement rather than using `console.log` to add a breakpoint; this makes inspecting your code easier. Once the breakpoint is hit, then type `repl` on your command line. From `repl` mode you can type arbitrary expressions--like `arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id`--and inspect the return value.) Use Ctrl+C to exit repl mode, and use `c` to continue execution.

Comment: I done `console.log(arrayOfObjects.commands[i].guild_id` right under the `for` loop and I got obviously the first object's `guild_id` in the JSON file. Adding it under the first `if` and I get nothing, as it doesn't get past.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142422/discussion-between-nb1987-and-rusty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the solution is helpful to anyone else, I discussed this with the OP in chat and discovered that the issue occurred because the OP wanted to compare the current `message`'s guild with the corresponding guild in the JSON data. Therefore, I suggested taking out the for loop completely and instead finding the guild first (using `find()`) and then doing a comparison:

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
if (args.length !== 1) return message.reply("Incorrect arguments, " + args.length + " given, 1 required.");
if (message.mentions.users.size !== 1) return message.reply("You must mention a user to view the commands of.");

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../jsonFiles") + "/customCommands.json", "utf-8", function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(data);

  if (arrayOfObjects.commands.length === 0) return message.reply("No custom commands found.");

  var guild = arrayOfObjects.commands.find(function(obj) { return obj.guild_id == message.guild.id; });

  if (message.guild.id !== guild.guild_id) return message.reply("No commands in guild.");
  if (message.guild.id !== guild.guild_id && user.id !== guild.user_id) return message.reply(user.username + " has no commands in this guild.");

  fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../jsonFiles") + "/customCommands.json", JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects, null, 2), "utf-8", function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0x08F258)
      .setAuthor("Custom Commands for " + user.username, message.author.avatarURL)
      .addField(guild.command_name, guild.command_reply)
       return message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
    });

});
```